# How can I automatically format a text file in Linux by a multi-occurring delimiter?

Tags: linux, text

I have a string of unicode that looks like this:

```
%ue8fc%u0089%u0000%u8960%u31e5%u64d2%u528b%u8b30%u0c52%u528b%u8b14%u2872%ub70f%u264
```

(but much much longer)

I'd like to automatically format it, making a new line every 7 "%"s

The final formatting for it looks like this - so to be able to get it to automatically format like this would be incredible - but a new line every 7 "%"s would at least be enough

```
"%u8b30%u0c52%u528b%u8b14%u2872%ub70f%u264a" +
"%uff31%uc031%u3cac%u7c61%u2c02%uc120%u0dcf" +
"%uc701%uf0e2%u5752%u528b%u8b10%u3c42%ud001" +
```

Is it possible to automate this type of formatting with a command?

Comment: Should be simple using `awk`. What have you tried?